# Android-How To Move Image Over Canvas on Touch Move And Get Image Exact Co-ordinates?

Tags: android, image, canvas

I am successful in moving the image over the canvas and getting co-ordinates of the image but when i pass the co-ordinates to next activity to combine a background image with the moveable the x co-ordinate of image doesnot change but the y co-ordinate changes and shifts upward and change is also not static as i move downward to screen the image shift increases.

Here's the Code -----

```
   class ImageMove extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public float mPosX;
public float mPosY;
public float mLastTouchX;
public float mLastTouchY;

//For Fetching image
private Bitmap bmp;
private Drawable image;
private byte[] byteArray;
private ByteArrayBuffer baf = null;

//For Rotation
int direction = 0;
int degree = 0;
private float centerX ;
private float centerY ;
private float newX ;
public float newY ;
private float rotateX;
private float rotateY;
private float imgX;
private float imgY;
GameThread thread;
int screenW; //Device's screen width.
int screenH; //Devices's screen height.

int initialY ;
float dY; //Image vertical speed.
int ImageW;
int ImageH;
int bgrW;
int bgrH;
int angle;
int bgrScroll;
int dBgrY; //Background scroll speed.
float acc;
Bitmap image, bgr;



//Measure frames per second.
long now;
int framesCount=0;
int framesCountAvg=0;
long framesTimer=0;
Paint fpsPaint=new Paint();

//Frame speed
long timeNow;
long timePrev = 0;
long timePrevFrame = 0;
long timeDelta;




public ImageMove(Context context) {
    super(context);
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bubble); //Load a  image.
   bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.grd); //Load a background.

   bgrW = bgr.getWidth();
   bgrH = bgr.getHeight();

   imageW = image.getWidth();
    imageH = image.getHeight();


    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener()); 
    //Set thread
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    //This event-method provides the real dimensions of this custom view.
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
    System.out.println(w+"  X  "+h);
    bgr = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgr, w, h, true); //Scale background to fit the screen.
    bgrW = bgr.getWidth();
    bgrH = bgr.getHeight();


}

//***************************************
//*************  TOUCH  *****************
//***************************************
@Override
public synchronized boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

     mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0); 
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            System.out.println("MOVE");
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;


                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;


        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            System.out.println("UP");
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;


        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            System.out.println("CANCEL");
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            System.out.println("ACTN_POINTER_UP");
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
            >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }

        }

        return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Rect fromRect1 = new Rect(0, 0, bgrW - bgrScroll, bgrH);
    Rect toRect1 = new Rect(bgrScroll, 0, bgrW, bgrH);

    Rect fromRect2 = new Rect(bgrW - bgrScroll, 0, bgrW, bgrH);
    Rect toRect2 = new Rect(0, 0, bgrScroll, bgrH);

    if (!reverseBackroundFirst) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, fromRect1, toRect1, null);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(bgrReverse, fromRect2, toRect2, null);
    }
    else{
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, fromRect2, toRect2, null);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(bgrReverse, fromRect1, toRect1, null);
    }



     canvas.drawText(mPosX+ "  X  "+mPosY, 40, 70, fpsPaint);
     canvas.drawText(imageW+ "  X  "+imageH, 40, 100, fpsPaint); 

     canvas.drawText(screenW+ "  X  "+screenH, 40, 150, fpsPaint);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}



@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}


class GameThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private ImageMove imageView;
    private boolean run = false;

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, ImageMove imageView) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        this.run = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (run) {
            c = null;

            //limit frame rate to max 60fps
            timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeDelta = timeNow - timePrevFrame;
            if ( timeDelta < 16) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(16 - timeDelta);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            timePrevFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                   //call methods to draw and process next fame
                    gameView.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: pls post what you have done so far.

Comment: pls help i would be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer actually I was taking the coordinates without taking the full-screen and the coordinates I was receiving were actually according to the full-screen